# Interpreted vs. Compiled XSLT 1.0 produces different JSON output

Tags: java, xml, json, xslt

Given the following XML:

```
<abc>
    <def>
       <one>Hello</one>
       <two>World</two>
    </def>
</abc>
```

And the XSL file to transform the XML to JSON available here: http://dropbox.ashlock.us/open311/json-xml/xml-tools/xml2json_spark.xsl

When transforming using **Interpreted XSLT** (PROCESSOR: Apache Software Foundation, javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory=org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl), the JSON output is:

```
{"abc":[{"one":"Hello","two":"World"}]}
```

When transforming using **Compiled XSLT** (PROCESSOR: Apache Software Foundation (Xalan XSLTC), javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory=org.apache.xalan.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl), the JSON output is:

```
[{"one":"Hello","two":"World"}]
```

Why do the 2 processors produce different results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saxon's output is the same as XSLTC:

```
[{"one":"Hello","two":"World"}]
```

I haven't attempted to debug the stylesheet in detail. It doesn't contain anything obviously implementation-defined, so it looks like a bug in Xalan-interpreted to me.

This pattern is questionable, though not illegal:

```
*[count(../*[name(../*)=name(.)])=count(../*) and count(../*)>1]
```

It's questionable because name(../*) is supplying a sequence of elements to the name function. That would be an error in XSLT 2.0, but in 1.0 mode it gives the name of the first selected element. I suspect that the author may have intended something like

```
*[count(../*[name(.)=name(current())])=count(../*) and count(../*)>1]
```